# Loss of Citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I am a British Citizen and my daughter who was born in the Philippines came to join me in the UK and acquired British nationality through child registration as she was only 12 when she arrived. She went to the Philippines last year in July 2016 with her British passport and she is also registered in the Philippines Embassy in London with dual nationality.
She is attending school in the Philippines at the moment and my question is if she wants to complete her education in the Philippines would she loose her British Nationality for being away from the UK. I do not want her to lose her Citizenship as I know she wants to come back to the UK and settle here.
Can you kindly advise me as to the contrary I would have to make arrangements for the new school term starting this September and where she attended for a whole year from September 2015 to July 2016. I would appreciate any advice. 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A British citizen remains a British citizen for life unless specific steps are taken by the citizen to renounce that citizenship, or extraordinary steps are taken by the government to revoke a person's citizenship (see [Loss of British nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_nationality_law#Loss_of_British_nationality) for full details). Your daughter will remain a British citizen for as long as she chooses to live overseas.

She will, of course, probably need to renew her passport while overseas. This can be done by mail without having to return to the UK.

Comment: "unless specific or extraordinary steps are taken to renounce that citizenship" or unless you are a dual national and the British government decides to strip your citizenship for security reasons

Comment: @user102008: I would consider that an "extraordinary step". One hopes that such action remains an extraordinary step.

Comment: Right, but that's not "renouncing", which is an action taken by the person.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I've changed the wording. Thanks.